How to preserve food (sauces, dips etc in jars) like the industry does it?
The goal is to make spreads, dips, sauces, mayonnaise and the like in a way that it's as stable as store bought one.
When I buy a jar of mayonnaise, it's good for months, even if I use dirty spoons to take some out.
When I make mayonnaise myself, on the other hand, it has turned bad after 7 days at the latest, no matter what I do.
When I read the label of store bought, I can't find anything in there, of which I know that it helps to preserve food. Just things like stabilizing/thickening agents. How can it be so stable? Maybe because they package under a protection sphere, but then it still would have to turn bad quickly after opening, but that's not the case. So what are they doing, that it's good for so long time?

“Spreads, dips, sauces, mayonnaise and the like” is an impossibly broad category, with different techniques being used for different foods. Making "long(er)-life" homemade mayonnaise covers the example you talked about. If you have questions about another food, you should ask a new question about it if it hasn’t been covered on this site.

Yes it is broad. I thought better one question than five, but maybe that's preferred here. I also see the use in it so I will open a new question. Mayonnaise was just an example, although the answer really helped!

You say the label lists 'things like stabilizing agents'... In foods, stabilizers prevent spoilage. For mayo, a common one is EDTA (also known as E385), which is listed on that page as a "preservative or stabilizer". I'd say the 'dirty spoon' doesn't have much to do with it, and the home-made mayo goes bad for other reasons: it's likely shifting because it has no stabilizer like that EDTA, and it's not going bad from added bacterial/fungal growth from a dirty spoon.
Adding those stabilizers is what the industry is doing different from your home-made mayonaise (and other sauces/dips etc.).
